# T-SQL, get highest values from two columns while grouping by one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to select the highest price for each id, but only the prices from the rows with the highest lastupdated column.

Using this query won't give me the correct price.

```
SELECT 
    id, MAX(price) as price, MAX(lastupdated) as lastupdated 
FROM 
    tbl 
GROUP BY 
    id
```

Sample tbl data:

```
id, price, lastupdated
1, 50, 2015-03-01
1, 51, 2015-03-01
1, 52, 2015-03-01
1, 53, 2015-02-28
1, 54, 2015-02-28
1, 55, 2015-02-28
2, 20, 2015-02-01
2, 21, 2015-02-01
2, 22, 2015-02-01
2, 33, 2015-01-28
2, 34, 2015-01-28
2, 35, 2015-01-28
```

The result I'd like is:

```
id, price, lastupdated
1, 52, 2015-03-01
2, 22, 2015-02-01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RANK` to assign a ranking number to each record of your table. Then use this number in an outer query to select all records with the most recent `lastupdated` value per `id`:

```
SELECT id, MAX(price) as price, lastupdated
FROM (
   SELECT id, price, lastupdated,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lastupdated DESC) AS rnk
   FROM tbl ) t  
WHERE t.rnk = 1 
GROUP BY id, lastupdated
```

Alternatively, you can use `HAVING` clause to filter out any (`id`, `lastupdated`)
groups not having the maximum `lastupdated` date value:

```
SELECT id, MAX(price) as price, lastupdated
FROM #tbl t1
GROUP BY id, lastupdated
HAVING lastupdated = (SELECT MAX(lastupdated) FROM #tbl t2 WHERE id = t1.id)
```

The query utilising the `HAVING` clause is more succint but less efficient, since the subquery it uses (`SELECT MAX(lastupdated) ...`) is evaluated once *for each group* defined in the outer query.

Comment: The latter (the `having` clause containing a correlated subquery) would probably cause nested loops in the execution plan that are unnecessary for this problem. See "correlated subquery".

Comment: Yeah, "the subquery is evaluated once for each group defined in the outer query". Avoid the having when a join is possible instead, e.g. jpw's solution. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179357(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @shannon Yes, you are absolutely right.I have included your comment in my answer. Correlated subqueries lead to higly inefficient queries in case there is a large number of records in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filtering `join` to only look at the rows with the latest date:

```
SELECT  tbl.id
,       MAX(price) as price
,       lastupdated 
FROM    Tel
JOIN    (
        SELECT  id
        ,       MAX(last_updated) as maxupdated
        FROM    tbl
        GROUP BY
                id
        ) mx
ON      tbl.id = mx.id
        AND tbl.lastupdated = mx.maxupdated
GROUP BY 
        tbl.id
,       last_updated
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the lastupdated for each id and join with that:

```
SELECT tbl.id, MAX(price) as price, m.lastupdated
FROM tbl 
JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(lastupdated) AS lastupdated 
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY id
) m ON tbl.id = m.id and tbl.lastupdated = m.lastupdated
GROUP BY tbl.id, m.lastupdated
ORDER BY tbl.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I feel like a cte is a good way to do it

```
with cte ( id, maxdate )
as
(
  select id, max(lastupdated)
  from tbl
  group by id
)
select 
     t3.id
    ,max(price)
    ,max(maxdate)
from 
    tbl t3 
        inner join cte on t3.id = cte.id and t3.lastupdated = cte.maxdate
group by
    t3.id
```